# I need class that will create rectangle using coordinates of the centers, high (X axis) and width (y axis)

Tags: java, constructor, rectangles

Rectangle is formed using on this test

```
 @Test
    public void testRectangle1() {
    Point center = new Point(20, 30);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(center, 20, 20);
    assertAll(
    () -> assertEquals(10, rect.getTopLeft().getX()),
    () -> assertEquals(20, rect.getTopLeft().getY()),
    () -> assertEquals(30, rect.getBottomRight().getX()),
    () -> assertEquals(40, rect.getBottomRight().getY()),
    () -> assertEquals(20, rect.getWidth()),
    () -> assertEquals(20, rect.getHeight())
        );
    }
```

I already have class for point it should work correctly i mostly add it for understanding.

```
public class Point {
    private int x, y;
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public Point() {
        this(0, 0);
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public void moveTo(int newX, int newY) {
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
    }
    public void moveRel(int dx, int dy) {
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Point other = (Point) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

So  i stuck in second class for rectangle itself. First of all i kinda have hard time forming consructor that will form rectangle itself. And also on filling methods in rectangle class, as i have hard time in uderstanding what they should return becouse i have little experience in Java and coding.

```
public class Rectangle {
    public int width = 0;
    public int height = 0;
    public Point center;

    public Rectangle(Point center, int width, int height) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        width=x;
        height=y;
    }

    public Point getTopLeft() {
        Point point = new Point();
        return point;
    }

    public Point getBottomRight() {
        Point point = new Point();
        return point;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        int x = 0;
        return x;
    }


    public int getHeight() {
        int y = 0;
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: You obviously need to pass x and y values to the points you create in `getTopLeft()` and `getBottomRight()`. Since you already have the _center_ point's coordinates as well as width and height of the rectangle those corner points' coordinates should be fairly easy to calculate. What difficulties did you run into? Btw, I urge you to read [ask] is you haven't already.

Comment: Just like `center`, add a `topLeft` and `bottomRight` `Point`to your `Rectangle`. In your constructor you can then calculate these `Point`s based on `center`, `width`, and `height`. In your `get` and `set` methods you then return these "variables" (i.e. fields). Do it on paper first, then it should become apparent.

Comment: As for your constructor: that looks fine. However, in `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` you need to return `width` and `height` instead of 0 (which is what you're effectively doing). Since this seems to be some kind of exercise I'd suggest you get in touch with your teacher or grab a tutorial on Java and programming basics because it if you're already struggling with this task you need to invest more work in getting the basics or you'll regret this later on. - Btw, did _you_ provide the `Point` class or did you get it from someone else?

Comment: Point is the part of exercise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getTopLeft()` and `getBottomRight()` you could create a point with center coordinates and then `moveRel(int, int)` it by width and height divided by 2, as you center point is in the middle of the both.

```
public Point getTopLeft() {
    Point point = new Point(center.getX(), center.getY());
    point.moveRel(- width / 2, height / 2);
    return point;
}

public Point getBottomRight() {
    Point point = new Point(center.getX(), center.getY());
    point.moveRel(width / 2, - height / 2);
    return point;
}
```

Constructor should write given values to the fields of the class.
Also consider using decimal type for the coordinates, only even height and width would be divisible by 2.

Comment: So if i understand this code will return coordinats of top lef and bottom right basd on center coordinates am i right?
i tried to empliment this code, but tests return only 0

Comment: you probably did not set the width and height in the constructor